# VirtualBox: Can't start Windows with Efi on Windows Host

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, efi

I want to start Windows Server 2019 in Virtual Box with a Windows 10 Host using Efi. But after checking the Efi Boot in the VirtualBox menu, this is the screen i see:

[image: Screen]

I've already tried:

```
fs0:
\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI
```

It then returns to an empty screen with:

```
FS0:\>
```

So I am stuck there.

I already tried older VirtualBox versions, but those won't start any virtual machine, even though I've deactivated Hyper-V in Windows Features and so on.

I am running out of ideas. The efi boot is essential for me, because I want to recover a domain controller and virtualize it as a test system. It cannot be recovered without efi.

My VirtualBox Version is `6.1.26 r145957 (Qt5.6.2)` and the extension package is installed.

Comment: Was Windows Server 2019 installed in legacy or UEFI mode?  Is Windows Server 2019 even installed on the VM?

Comment: @Ramhound , I can install Windows Server 2019 in legacy (in vbox it's called "boot") and it runs perfectly. But I am using Windows Server Backup for the backup of my active directory. And since the actual hardware domain controller is booting with uefi, the virtual box needs to start in efi, too. 
Every other OS is not booting with efi in vbox too, so the problem (in my opinion) is not to seek in windows server 2019. It might be the virtualbox version for windows, I didn't try an other host os.

Comment: Have you considered VMWare Player and/or Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox?  I assume you ran `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware efi` on the VM?  I personally moved away from VirtualBox years ago due to quality issues

Comment: VMWare is with costs, so no. But I tried Hyper-V and it won't boot either. Could it be a problem coming from my host?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP.  Even though I manually edited the startup.nsh file to specify the path of where bootx64.efi resides, it wouldn't load my bootx64.efi file.  If I manually navigated to the directory and entered 'bootx64.efi' at the command prompt, it wouldn't do anything.

Ultimately what fixed it was this for me:

1. In VirtualBox, select the Settings for your VM.
2. Under general, make sure the correct OS is listed.  In my case, I had to specify Windows 2016 as it wasn't already selected.

After making these changes, I was able to successfully start my VM in VirtualBox.

I hope this helps others.